# Force visual studio to error on include with incorrect capatilization

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

in Visual Studio 2008 c++ it would rock if one could force a compile error for incorrect capitalization on a header include. (ThisIsAHeader.h VS thisIsAheader.h)

I know windows is case-insensitive file system. The issue comes because one inadvertently breaks the linux build while developing on windows due to getting the header file name wrong.

One could save quite a few cycles of unnecessary build breakage if there was a way to make cl.exe throw up a compile error.

Assumptions: One can not dictate the windows dev team switch to using something other than Visual Studio, and one can not change all headers to be all lowercase.

Comment: If your team uses some kind of VCS you could run a pre-commit script that parses all .cpp files and tries to match all #included files with files on disk, searching for case sensitive mismatches.

Comment: @Dialecticus: Right. Have shown this in more detail as an answer to the linked question.